# PHP Locate a stored file by a part of its name

Tags: php, image, file, storage, locate

friends.
I need to locate a file, stored in my site while using php and finding it with a part of its name. I cant locate it by its entire name because the php file cannot know its extension. It might be png and might be jpg.

How do I do that?

Comment: What have you tried? How do you plan to handle files with the same name, but different extensions?

Comment: is it only ever going to be either FILE.png or FILE.jpg?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`glob()`](http://php.net/glob)

Here's an example:

```
<?php

foreach(glob("path/to/files/imagename.*") as $file)
{
    // do something with the file here
    echo $file;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You will want to look at [`glob`](http://php.net/glob).